# How to create Cron job in wordpress which run 3 times daily and update post author role from author to subscriber if post field value matches date?

Tags: wordpress, cron, cron-task

I am very bigginer at coding. I wan tot create an auto cron job system in wordpress which will update the user role and post if specific condition met. The system is just like membeship plugin as our membership expires we are unable to acess some things. Here is the same senario with some different method:

```
// Schedule event to run daily
function schedule_custom_role_update() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'custom_role_update' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'custom_role_update' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'schedule_custom_role_update' );

// Function to run when event is triggered
function update_post_author_role() {
    // Get current date
    $current_date = date( 'Y-m-d' );

    // Get all posts that have the custom field "expiry_date" set
    $args = array(
        'meta_key'   => 'expiry_date',
        'meta_value' => $current_date,
        'post_type'  => 'post',
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();

        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
        $author = get_user_by( 'ID', $author_id );
        $author->set_role( 'editor' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_action( 'custom_role_update', 'update_post_author_role' );
```

I dont now if this code is workign:
I want to make a cron job which will run automatically 3 times or 5 times a day and it will check the all post in properties post type.

In properties post type I have custom taxanomy term assign to posts callled "Pro Property".
Also, there is a custom field in property post type with name/id called "expiry_date".
So lets say if user has 3 post and from 3 post they have 1 post which contain "Pro Property" term and expiry date in their meta they have already user role called "author".
but if all of their posts dont have any term assign with name "pro preopert" we will update their role.

Condition:
So lets say if in some psot expiry date is set to 20/1/2024 cron job will match that date with our current life time and if these both dates get matched. It will update the post author role from author to subscriber.
&
Automatically unassign the term "Pro Property" from that post and remove the expiry date from psot meta also.

So both author and that post get updated automatically IF "expiry_date" field and current date get matched.

I dont now if it is posssible or not.

I want to see cron jobs system power and want to uise this code in live project of mine.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: By default wordpress have the following intervals - hourly, twicedaily, daily. How to create own interval - https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/understanding-wp-cron-scheduling/ .

Comment: @MartinMirchev Thanks for the reply. I don't have any knowledge of coding. IS above code is working? I dont care if its run 1 time a dat. I jsut want to check if post meta nd current date is dame then update that post author role from author to subscriber